# How to run scenarios in sequence in feature files with different data set

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a task in which I have to run all of my tests in feature file with multiple combinations of country and language and they should run in sequence. We have list of countries and languages in app and my feature file has 10 scenarios based on each country/language pair the application UI is different. I tried with scenario outline but the problem is I can only run one scenario with multiple combinations of country and language the scenarios don't get interlinked to each other. I need to do the following

1. Select Country and Language
2. Go to Account screen
3. Login
4. Go to My Products
5. Add products
   The other screen ui elements and products changes based on the selected country/language so the scenarios should run in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your steps in a generic way e.g. `When I set my country and language` you can get the country and language you want to use from the environment. Then you can change the country and language before each cuke run. Building on that you could write a script that loops over a set of languages changing the environment and running your cukes. You could go even further and collect the results in the script and aggregate them into a single entity.

You might find that only a subset of your features really need to be tested with multiple languages. You can take two approaches to this

1. Put all your multi-language features in a folder
2. Use a tag for multi-language features

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a scenario outline as below :

Select "Country" and Language
Go to Account screen
Login
Go to My Products
Add products
Examples :
|Country|
|UK|

Inside the first step you will store the country value in a variable which you will do use in the last step as below:

switch(Country) {
case UK:
// fill UK fields ()
break;
case USA:
// fill UK fields ()
break;
default:
// code block
}